how to pass parameter to app store and get it on install?
I used universal link to pass parameters for installed app. That works perfectly. But whereas I don’t know how to pass parameters to App Store and get it once the app installed.
Example: I have a website say, example.com. I kept applinks:example.com?id=1.
I can able to retrieve the id=1 in the ios app as universal link.
But unable to get the same when user installed the app on first time.
Need any way to pass parameters to App Store and get it from there.
I tried the Smart App Banner from Apple. But it’s not the case, if user installs app via QR code that time it won’t work.

I am dealing with the same scenario and the most suitable ways are as follows...

Dynamic links from Firebase (which will be deprecated soon so not recommended)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links
Use services such as branch.io or AppsFlyer (They provide the exact service you want)

https://www.branch.io/
https://www.appsflyer.com/

Use a clipboard. When you are redirected to your website through a universal link, you can store the required data in a clipboard and then try to get data from the clipboard when the app opens on a fresh install.


Thank you for your comments. Clipboard i have checked it, but it's showing popup when we get the string, without popup i can't able to achieve this. Is there any other way without thirdparty?

there is a referral link in Android but in iOS I think that is not available... I haven't gotten any other solution yet and for now, I don't think that we can achieve this kind of feature by ourselves.

Ok, Thank you for your response, i checked dynamic-links its deprecated, is there any other google services to track the parameters?

I have already given you the other 2 service links. You can check here also https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration

Thank you for suggestion. I used the third party service to achieve this.

Cool, but how do those services work???
